# Re-compressing XZ kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, compression, kernel-modules, compilation

I have a kernel module produced by kernel option CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_XZ. When I manually decompress the file with unxz and re-compress with xz, the new .ko.xz file differs from the original .ko.xz only in 5 bytes. Apart of that the resultant files are identical, same length, etc - please see the attached screenshot of vbindiff.

Modinfo on both .ko.xz files is identical. Yet modprobe refuses to load the re-compressed module with "Exec format error".
Please what is the correct method of compressing a module, for example when compiling a modified module  (compression occurs in make modules_install which makes no sense to call  when re-compiling a single module).

Thanks a lot,

Pavel.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMRP3.png

Comment: the four bytes in a row that differ are simply a CRC32 of the header ... the lone byte difference seems to indicate that the top file uses 16MB Dictionary Size for LZMA2 filter vs 2MB for the bottom file - don't understand why the compressed data is the same though

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the difference. The uncompressed file is only 35kB and fits into the 2MB dictionary - that's probably the reason there are no other differences in the two files. Using

xz  --lzma2=dict=2MiB snd-soc-rockchip-i2s-tdm.ko

produces identical file.

Please do you know why modprobe refuses the module compressed with the different directory size? Does it keep some checksum to compare? Thanks a lot!

Comment: absolutely no idea, sorry